# Test call back function sent to a child element using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

There is a function in my parent class that is being sent to the Child component, it is not being used else where. How can I achieve coverage for this code. I want to avoid using `mount` and use `shallow` only.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  callBackFn() {
    console.log("Some call back function");
  }
  render(){
    return (<div>
        <ChildComponent someFunct="callBackFn" />
      </div>);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let wrapper = shallow(<Parent/>);
wrapper.find(ChildComponent).prop('someFunct')();
```

This can execute your function and code will get covered.

Comment: Thank you @sanket-phansekar, for a quick response.